# Get sum of lenghth of all Strings in Object in ArrayList of this object using lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have an array list which contains objects of this class:

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value; 
}
```

How to count length of all Strings in all objects in this ArrayList?
It can be done in foreach, but I suppose it also can be done in lambda, but I dont know how do it sneaky and modern.

now my solution is:

```
Integer sum=0;
        for (SearchCriteria s: builder.getParams()
             ) {
            sum+=s.getKey().length();
            sum+=s.getOperation().length();
            sum+=s.getValue().toString().length();
        }
```

Comment: You should have a look into the `mapToInt(String::length).sum()` method for Streams which does basically what you want. Just need to apply it to your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMapToInt` to convert a `Stream<SearchCriteria >` to an `IntStream` containing the lengths of all the properties of the elements of the original `Stream`:

```
int sum = builder.getParams()
                 .stream()
                 .flatMapToInt(sc -> IntStream.of(sc.getKey().length(),sc.getOperation().length(),sc.getValue().toString().length()))
                 .sum();
```

Comment: nice one, you could also just map it to an int and then reduce it

Comment: @jojo_Berlin well, if you map to an int which is the sum of the lengths of all the properties of a given SearchCriteria, that would work.

Comment: After correcting `sc.getValue().length()` to `sc.getValue().toString().length()` this is IMO the cleanest answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is useful to you, but you can try this:

```
List<SearchCriteria> criterion = builder.getParams();
int sum = criterion.stream().map(s -> s.getKey() + s.getOperation() + s.getValue())
                   .mapToInt(String::length).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
List<SearchCriteria> list = ...
int sum = list.stream()
          .flatMapToInt(crit -> Arrays.stream(new int[] {
              crit.getKey().length(), 
              crit.getOperation().length(), 
              crit.getValue().toString().length()}))
          .sum();
```

This makes an int stream of all `length` values and simply sums them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sum in a straight way different things of the streamed element.
So as alternative, I would extract the computation logic in a `SearchCriteria` method such as :

```
public int computeAllLength(){
   return key.length() + operation.length() + value.toString().length();
}
```

And I would use it in this way :

```
int sum = builder.getParams().stream()
                 .mapToInt(SearchCriteria::computeAllLength)
                 .sum();
```